# magento 2 - How to rearrange column of product grid?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, product-grid

How to rearrange column of product grid ?

[image]

Comment: drag and drop maybe?

Comment: I want to custom code, I tried to edit in gird.php but it did not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in below file

vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml

There is code for status column like below adjust it as per you want

```
<column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
 </column>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem below: In Grid.php of block I override method *_prepareColumns*

```
.........       
$this->addColumnAfter(
                'status',
                [
                        'header' => __('Status'),
                        'index' => 'status',
                        'type' => 'options',
                        'options' => $this->_status->getOptionArray()
                ],
                'entity_id'
        );
...............
```

Comment: can you share details.

Answer (score 1):

No code required, drag and drop the column headers.